# link_to nested resource in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am creating a jobs board with employers and jobs. How would I go about linking my job.title to the job show action/view?

jobs/index.html.erb

```
<% @jobs.each do |job| %>
  <%= link_to job.title, ?? %>
<% end %>
```

jobs_controller.rb

```
def index
  @jobs = Job.all
end

def show
  @job = Job.find(params[:id])
end
```

employers_controller.rb

```
def index
  @employers = Employer.all
end

def show
  @employer = Employer.find(params[:id])
end
```

job.rb

```
belongs_to :employer
```

employer.rb

```
has_many :jobs
```

routes.rb

```
resources :jobs, only: %i[index], :path => 'jobb'
resources :employers, only: %i[index show], :path => 'arbetsgivare' do
  resources :jobs, only: %i[show], :path => 'jobb'
end
```

Comment: go to your terminal and type `rake routes | grep job` and see what path is written with "show"

Comment: thanks kuwantum for your comment. It only says "employer_job" for show action but that doesn't work since it seems to be missing the employer_id. I am certainly missing something.

Comment: try `employer_job_path(job)`, so it looks like `<%= link_to job.title, employer_job_path(job) %>`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This one should do the trick:

```
<%= link_to job.title, employer_job_path(job.employer, job) %>
```

Rails need two ids to build the route in your case, so you have to pass to route helper two objects.